# Where to ask a question about what language/framework to use for coding a math game?

Tags: support

I am wanting to write a little math training game that can run in the browser where users can do exercises with, addition, subtraction, division, multiplication, in a range from 0 - 100.

The exercises are in this form. 12 - __ = 8, or 5 x   6 = __ or __ / 4  = 3,
where basically the result can be filled into the equation.

So I am looking for advice what language/framework and set up could be used and not really sure where to ask this. SO or Software Engineering or somewhere else?

Comment: see also: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

Answer (score 1):

The question wouldn't fit on either Stack Overflow or Software Engineering. It may fit on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but [they have very strict guidelines for what a question should look like](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). In general, it's very difficult to make a question like this fit in the Q&A format - it tends to attract opinions rather than facts.